# array_eq_sub behavior for zero length

Tags: why3

I have the following lemma in `why3`:

```
lemma trivial:
  forall a : array 'a, b : array 'a.
  array_eq_sub a b 0 0
```

This seems like it would be the base case behavior, but apparently isn't.  Any ideas on why this isn't working?

**UPDATE** 
I was able to reduce the issue to a single missing lemma:

```
lemma array_eq_2:
  forall a : array 'a, b : array 'a.
  map_eq_sub a.elts b.elts 0 0 -> array_eq_sub a b 0 0
```

This seems trivial as well, given the definition of `array_eq_sub` as specified in [the documentation](http://why3.lri.fr/stdlib-0.82/array.mlw.html#array_eq_sub_135).  Why can't my prover find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this issue, I decided to take a look at the `why3` source code.  I found a definition which was different from what was documented:

```
predicate array_eq_sub (a1 a2: array 'a) (l u: int) =
  a1.length = a2.length /\ 0 <= l <= a1.length /\ 0 <= u <= a1.length /\
  map_eq_sub a1.elts a2.elts l u
```

In short, the lengths of the arrays have to be equal in order for a portion of them to be equal.  This was different than what was documented, and I suspect may be causing many theorems to be unsound.